# How to put Copyright notice If I use several other code bases (MIT)

Tags: licensing, mit, copyright

If I use piece of code from some other repo which is under MIT licence I can directly use/show their Copyright info in my repo. That part is OK.

But what happenes if I get several pieces of code from different repositories with different copyright, which all are under the MIT licence.

Should I keep all the copyright notes? Or should I create one of my own?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Have you checked, how it is properly done in big OSS projects with many dependencies, for example https://github.com/mozilla-mobile/firefox-ios ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MIT license clearly says:

> The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

So, place ALL copyright notices and one license text.

When You take code for example from 3 repositories with the following licenses:

- Repository 1: MIT license, copyright notice: (C) 2022 Author of repo 1
- Repository 2: MIT license, copyright notice: (C) 2022 Author of repo 2
- Repository 3: MIT license, copyright notice: (C) 2022 Author of repo 3

If you want to use MIT license for your project:

Just take all of these notices and place into LICENSE file like that:

(C) 2022 Author of repo 1

(C) 2022 Author of repo 2

(C) 2022 Author of repo 3

[Here your notice]

and here MIT license text.

If You want to use them in commercial product or product under another license, just make a NOTICE file with all copyright notices as above, but without yours. You can specify that You used code from those project.

Note: This is not legal advice! I'm not a lawyer.